# How to open port for transmission bittorent while using internet from USB tethering?

Tags: networking, ufw, bittorrent, port-forwarding, tethering

I have a router and an old desktop pc running Lubuntu 16.04 64Bit. 
I use internet on my desktop PC like this:

I connect my android phone (Marshmallow, Lenovo K 4 Note) to the wifi network of my router. Then I connect my phone to PC using USB cable and turn on USB tethering.
The problem is, even if I enable UPNP, or manually add ports for port forwarding, transmission torrent shows my port as closed. I've tried disabling ufw, I've also tried enabling ufw with exclusion for the port.
Still the port is shown as closed.
I tried many sites which check for open ports, they all show my port is closed.
What Should I do to open the port?
Is the android phone blocking incoming connection?
My connection is Jio.
Screenshots attached.[image: Transmission]
[image: UFW status]
[image: Router settings]

Update:
Just noticed one of the peers is an incoming connection when I moved the mouse cursor over the IP address of the peer. But the Settings window of transmission still shows **the port is closed**. Any idea how is this happening ? Screenshot attached as the 4th picture. 
[image: Incoming connection found after some days]

Comment: But their router set up page provides option for turning port forwarding on. Why would they keep that option if they don't allow it? Is there an ISP in India which provides port forwarding?

Comment: Indeed. I though you were tethering mobile data, not wifi. Yes, with the port open both at ufw and the router it should work so, it's probably the phone itself blocking it.

Comment: @MichaelBay can I use adb forward command to enable port forwarding in my phone?

Comment: Sorry, don't know.

Comment: @NewtoUbuntu It's usually *not* something you can open on the phone - most mobile data / wifi connections from the phone don't let you do any type of port-forwarding as they operate as a pure NAT router and not much more.  You'd have to investigate that issue with your phone (offtopic here) or with your phone's mobile service provider (since they can block this upstream from your phone as well).

Comment: @MichaelBay Please find the 4th pic. Transmission shows a peer as incoming connection. No idea how this is  happening.  The setting window still shows the port is closed. Please find the updated question

Comment: @ThomasWard Please find the 4th pic. Transmission shows a peer as incoming connection. No idea how this is happening. The setting window still shows the port is closed. Please find the updated question

Comment: is it possible that ISP is using a big router to avoid the shortage of ipv4 addresses, and that router is not set up for UPNP ? And  port forwarding is working only with ipv6 connection? The external IPv 4 address shown in router setup page and IPv4 address shown by google are different

Comment: The router setup page shows an ipv6 address but some sites which test ipv6 shows no ipv6 detected